# Full screen mode is not working in selenium chromedriver headless mode

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

For example, I need to check is full screen is enabled or not after clicking the "Full Screen" icon in youtube.

When we run the script in UI, we can check with using of executing this "document.fullscreenElement" script. It is working.

But I need to run same in headless mode. It returns null and I have checked with using of taking a screenshot.

Is this possible in headless mode?

I have written a script in "ruby" using "selenium-webdriver".

Below script is running in UI mode successfully. But when we use -headless to chromeoptions it is not working.

```
require "selenium-webdriver"
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
driver.get("https://youtube.com/<any video url>")
driver.action.move_to(driver.find_element(:css,".ytp-right-controls")).perform
driver.find_element(:css,".ytp-fullscreen-button").click
driver.execute_script('return document.fullscreenElement').nil?
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you run headless? Some X emulators like Xvfb require that you specify a resolution of your display, otherwise apps won't be able to go fullscreen or maximized. See this example:

```
export DISPLAY=:1  
Xvfb $DISPLAY -screen 0 1024x768x16 &  
ruby mytest.rb
```

Answer (score 0):

Chrome in its native headless mode doesn't support fullscreen mode because it doesn't really know about the screen.  You can resize it to any size you like, but it won't see that as full screen.